# Value of tan with complex angle.

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, logarithms

The value of

$$\tan \biggl( i \log\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}-i}{\sqrt{2}+i}\right)\biggr) $$  is equal to?

$A. 2+i\sqrt2$

$B. 2-i\sqrt2$

$C. 2\sqrt2$

$D. 2\sqrt2i$

I thought in the inner parenthesis would be in form of $\cos (x) +i \sin (x)$ which can be written as $e^{ix}$ that would simplify the problem.

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you do the inner function?

Comment: Well , I thought in the inner parenthesis would be in form of $cos x +i sinx$ which can be written as $e^ix$ that would simplify the problem.

Comment: It's the third raw question you ask without any comment...

Comment: @Bridget I have moved your thought to the question body since comments do not last forever.

Comment: You've been given two incorrect answers. The correct answer is D, See my comments after each answer.

Answer (score 2):

By Euler formulas for $\sin$ and $\cos$:

$$\tag{1}\tan(z)=\tfrac{1}{i}\dfrac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}=-i\dfrac{e^{2iz}-1}{e^{2iz}+1}$$

Taking

$$\tag{2}z=i \log\left(u\right) \ \text{with} \ u:=\frac{\sqrt{2}-i}{\sqrt{2}+i},$$

(1) becomes:

$$\tag{3}\tan(z)=-i\dfrac{e^{-2 \log(u)}-1}{e^{-2 \log(u)}+1}=-i\dfrac{\tfrac{1}{u^2}-1}{\tfrac{1}{u^2}+1}=-i\dfrac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}$$

Plugging in (3) the expression of $u$ given above in (2)  gives the result

$$\tag{3}\tan(z)=-i\dfrac{(\sqrt{2}-i)^2-(\sqrt{2}+i)^2}{(\sqrt{2}-i)^2+(\sqrt{2}+i)^2}=2\sqrt{2}i.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that : $$\frac{\sqrt 2-i}{\sqrt 2+i}=\frac 13-i\frac{2\sqrt2}{3}=\exp \left(-i\arccos\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\right)$$

And hence $$\tan \left( i \log\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}-i}{\sqrt{2}+i}\right)\right)=\tan \left( i \log(\exp(-i\arccos\left(\frac{1}{3}\right))\right)=\tan\left( \arccos \left(\frac 13\right) \right) =2\sqrt 2 $$

Comment: One can do it in another way (see coming answer).